# access a method in anther class which contain a private variables

Tags: java, private, overwrite, super

I have CreditCard class that contain a private variable

```
private double balance;
```

and a method charge like

```
public boolean charge(double price){
    if (price + balance > limits)
        return false;
    balance += price;
    return true;
}
```

Why the method charge in class `PredatoryCreditCard` flawed ??

```
public boolean charge(double price){
    boolean isSuccess = super.charge(price);
    if(!isSuccess)
        super.charge(5); //*** here the penalty
    return isSuccess;
}
```

and even when we write `charge(5);` without super keyword flawed ??

Comment: If you call `charge(5)` without `super`, then you're calling yourself, and may end up in an infinite recursion (until `StackOverflowError`). The `super.charge(5)` should work fine, but a hardcoded price of `5` may still exceed the `limit`, so it may return false.

Comment: What do you mean by flawed what is the error or what do you want to fix ?

Comment: If variable balance declared as private not protected is not that affect in accessing charge method?

Comment: No, you can not access it directly, but you are allowed to call a public method that has access to it.